# Force download Windows update to build 14316

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I’d like to try the new Ubuntu Bash on Windows, I’m already on the insider preview program and every time that I do a “check for updates” I don’t get any new update.

My current build is 10585.218 and I’m aware that I need to install the build 14316, is there any way to force Windows to update to that specific build?

Comment: There is indeed.  Download the current Windows Insider .ISO, typically it seems based on 3 other questions on this very subject, it takes about 3 days to automatically get it through Windows Update.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound I waited more than 3 days and I can't get the update and installing the iso isn't an option for me, any other suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Continue to wait or use the .ISO method

Answer (score 0):

this looks like an promising answer by some editing the registry:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/insider-program-stuck-at-release-10586-windows/6d3f0621-dc84-4bd0-a468-2219a26e5a34?msgId=7b4c89b5-96b4-4b72-b520-7472d87d76c4

Comment: I tried it but i didn't work for me